# Static referenced in another .cs file

Tags: c#

I am overlooking something simple I think.  I have a form with a checkbox.  I need to know if the checkbox is checked in a different cs file/class to know whether to make a column header Option1 or Option2.
Form1 (Public partial class) code:

```
public bool Checked
{
    get 
    { 
        return checkBox1.Checked; 
    }   
}
```

In my Export1 class I have private void CreateCell1 that takes in the data to be exported (creating an excel file from a datatable).  The section of code I can't get to work is:

```
if (Form1.Checked.Equals("true"))
{
    newRow["Option1"] = date2;
}
else
{
    newRow["Option2"] = date2;
}
```

I am getting -Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Matrix1.Form1.Checked.get'

What did I overlook?

Comment: `Form1` is the name of the class - you need an actual object (as `Checked` is not `static`)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the problem here is exactly what the compiler is telling you. You need an **object reference** in order to access the property.

Allow me to explain.

In C#, by default, class members (fields, methods, properties, etc) are *instance* members. This means that they are tied to the instance of the class they are a part of. This enables behavior like the following:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dog1 = new Dog { Age: 3 };
        var dog2 = new Dog { Age: 5 };
    }
}
```

The two instances of `Dog` both have the property `Age`, however the value is tied to that instance of `Dog`, meaning that they can be different for each one.

In C#, as with a lot of other languages, there are things called [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) members of classes. When a class member is declared `static`, then that member is no longer tied to an instance of the class it is a part of. This means that I can do something like the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static string bar = "bar";
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.bar);
    }
}
```

The `bar` field of the `Foo` class is declared `static`. This means that it is the same for all instances of `Foo`. In fact, we don't even have to initialize a new instance of `Foo` to access it.

The problem you are facing here is that, while `Form1` is not a static class and `Checked` is not a static property, you are treating it as such. In order for what you are trying to do to work, you need to create an *instance* of `Form1` and access that instance's `Checked` property.

Depending on how your program is structured, there are many ways of doing this. If `Form1` is created in the scope where you are trying to access `Checked`, then this will be straightforward. If `Form1` is what spawns the new scope, then common practice is to pass a reference to it in the constructor.

For example, if `Form1` creates a new `Form2` then we do the following:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 parent;
    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then you can access `parent` throughout `Form2`. Of course, depending on the structure of your program, the exact implementation will be different. However, the general pattern is the same. Pass the reference to `Form1`, from the scope it was created in, to the new class, and then access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you need to access the specific instance of `Form1` that you're trying to check.

A few ways to do this are:

1. Pass the instance to the class constructor
2. Setting a public property of the other class to the instance of the form
3. Pass the instance to the method directly

For example:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    // One option is to have a public property that can be set
    public Form1 FormInstance { get; set; }

    // Another option is to have it set in a constructor
    public SomeOtherClass(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.FormInstance = form1;
    }

    // A third option would be to pass it directly to the method
    public void AMethodThatChecksForm1(Form1 form1)
    {
        if (form1 != null && form1.Checked)
        {
            // Do something if the checkbox is checked
        }
    }

    // This method uses the local instance of the Form1 
    // that was either set directly or from the constructor
    public void AMethodThatChecksForm1()
    {
        AMethodThatChecksForm1(this.FormInstance);
    }
}
```

This class would need to be instantiated by the instance `form1` using one of these methods:

```
// Pass the instance through the constructor
var someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(this);

// Or set the value of a property to this instance
someOtherClass.FormInstance = this;

// Or pass this instance to a method of the class
someOtherClass.AMethodThatChecksForm1(this);
```